# I am using Raspberry PI + BHI 160 shuttle board + BMM150,How to get data from sensors into Raspberry PI using any binary?

Tags: android, c, raspberry-pi, embedded, sensors

I am using Raspberry PI + BHI 160 shuttle board + BMM150,How to get data into Raspberry PI using binary.

Can I use [**this**](https://github.com/BoschSensortec/BMI160_driver.git) driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you linked to is driver code for taking directly to the BMI160, the BHI160 is a BMI160 with a microcontroller.  The Shuttle Board's communication is with the microcontroller, not the BMI160 - so that code many not help you.

The BHI160 has an I2C interface. For details of how to access the I2C on RPi see [this tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-pi-spi-and-i2c-tutorial).  Then you should perhaps look at the documents and driver code at [the product's web page](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/bst/products/all_products/bhi160) for how to actually use the device.  They include a link to [examples and driver](https://github.com/BoschSensortec/BHy1_driver_and_MCU_solution), with a doc folder that includes a driver porting guide (i.e how to hook the BHI160 driver with teh RPi i2C driver and other platform specifics).

There are additional BHI160 specific application notes [here](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/bst/support_tools/downloads/overview_downloads).

What I am really saying is *read the documentation*.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I will let you know if I stuck somewhere.

Comment: My RPi has android OS running, and as per it's datasheet, BHI160 can provide full Android sensor stack to application. So I think I don't need to focus on this stuff, In stead of that I should focus on https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-types , Am I right ?

Comment: @HarshilMakwana : And you did not think that your unusual platform was worth mentioning in the question!? That makes in an Android question more than an RPi. I would not have wasted my time had you made that clear.

Comment: Sorry for that, Next time I will consider that. But As per your suggestion, I read documentation, and found that it is android supported. So your answer is worthy for me.